# Efficient inplane rotation of 2D grid in matlab from

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have to generate a series of 2D grid in matlab in some local coordinate systems, e.g:

```
xC = 0:0.2:10;
yC = 0:0.1:1;
[xlocal,ylocal] = meshgrid(xC,yC);
```

Over the local coordinates a scalarfield is defined, for instance:

```
scalarField = xlocal.^2+ylocal.^2;
contourf(xlocal,ylocal,scalarField);
```

Now I would to plot the "scalarField" in a global reference system X,Y. So I should take every coordinate pair and apply an (in plane) rotation+translation. The only idea I have is a "for" loop over all the coordinates, but it seems to be quite slow (I have many grids).

May you devise a better code?

Comment: Share your loopy code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by myself. Instead of rotating the whole grid I simply regenerate a new one that assures the mapping. The code itself is a way more readable than by using loops. I'm posting for whom may have the same issues. 
In any case further and faster contributions are welcome!!

```
 [xloc,yloc] = meshgrid(s,t); %mesh in local coordiantes
%% get grid in global coordiantes
getX = @(coord1,coord2) R(1,:)*[coord1; coord2] + c(1);
getY = @(coord1,coord2) R(2,:)*[coord1; coord2] + c(2);
Xgrid = arrayfun(getX,xloc,yloc);
Ygrid = arrayfun(getY,xloc,yloc);
```